# Bohr Sommerfeld in the quantum well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

The Bohr Sommerfeld rule is given by:

$$\oint p dx = 2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2} \right) $$
for potentials of the form
$$u_0(x)-\lambda. $$

The proof I was presented pertained to a particle moving in a 1D quantum well but it lacked enough detail for me to make sense of it. Does anyone know of a better derivation? I know Landau mentions it. I started with a square well with discrete energy values:

[image]